# How do you take divergence of this field?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, physics, symbolic-computation, derived-functors

I forgot how to do divergences 3 years ago, this one is very confusing. We used to take them with respect to $x,y,z$ but this one doesn't have them. Help me with this question

Prove that $∇.E = 0$

$E = \frac{IΔz}{4π}jwμ\bigg[1 + \frac{1}{jBr} - \frac{1}{{(Br)}^2}\bigg]\frac{{e}^{-jBr}}{r}\sin(θ) \hat θ + \frac{IΔz}{2π}η\bigg[\frac{1}{r} -\frac{j}{{Br}^2}\bigg]\frac{{e}^{-jBr}}{r}\cos(θ)\hat r$

Comment: If the above field is in coordinates $r, \theta$ and $\hat{\theta}$ (usually $\phi$) then it could be expressed in cylindrical coordinates http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#Cylindrical_coordinates

Comment: Where does $E$ come from? Is it $∇$$\times $$F = E$, because then we have ∇.(∇xF)  = 0.

Comment: i think E is just a formular of its own.

Comment: What is $\theta$? Is this a planar field with $(r,\theta)$ polar coordinates in the plane, or is it a field in three dimensions, with $\theta$ being the angle to the $z$ axis? And what are all other symbols? Just constants?

Comment: @Autolatry: $\hat{\theta}$ isn't an angle, it's the unit basis vector in the direction of increasing $\theta$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Oh gosh, silly me! I was too quick in wanting it to be in cylindrical coordinates that I completely forgot about the unit basis vector. Thank you Hans.

Comment: @Autolatry: (If you have two angles $\theta$ and $\phi$, it's spherical coordinates, not cylindrical...)

Comment: i think he symbols are just constants. probably theta and r will be the ones to matter

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes Hans, I know that but I thought I saw three, I thought I saw a "hatted" parameter.

Comment: Is it $B_r$ or $B.r$ - I can't see.